# Set similar width to columns in bootstrap datatable

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I want to create a datatable with similar column width, also I want it should be responsive.
I have created below fiddle for the same.
[Working example here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/qyjxd0gk/3/)

For column width I have added following css

```
table.table-bordered.dataTable th, table.table-bordered.dataTable td {
    white-space: normal!important;
}
table.table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;         
  word-wrap:break-word;   
}
```

Also changed in js code

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  "scrollY": "300px",
  "scrollCollapse": true,
  "bAutoWidth": false,
  "aoColumns": [
       { "sWidth": "10%" }, 
       { "sWidth": "15%" }, 
       { "sWidth": "10%" },
       { "sWidth": "10%" }, 
       { "sWidth": "10%" }, 
       { "sWidth": "10%" },
       { "sWidth": "10%" }, 
       { "sWidth": "10%" }, 
       { "sWidth": "10%" } 
      ]
 });
```

After changes it looks like as follow
https://fiddle.jshell.net/qyjxd0gk/4/

How to set width to columns with responsive datatable?

Answer (score 0):

Change the css as follow:

```css
@media screen and (min-width : your_target_screen_size px)
{
  table.table-bordered.dataTable th, table.table-bordered.dataTable td {
    ...  
  }
}
```

and added meta tag to html head

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```